# What's the most efficient way to split out columns from a string in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a very large table in BigQuery where data comes in as a space-delimited field that I need parsed into columns.  I've been using the SPLIT() function in BigQuery to parse this out but it feels inefficient.

Let's just say this is an example of one of the records:

```
firstname lastname timestamp eventtype errorcode
```

And here's an example of how I'm splitting the field into different columns:

```
SELECT SPLIT(unparsed_field, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]  AS first,
       SPLIT(unparsed_field, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]  AS last,
       SPLIT(unparsed_field, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(2)]  AS timestamp,
       SPLIT(unparsed_field, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(3)]  AS eventtype,
       SPLIT(unparsed_field, " ")[SAFE_OFFSET(4)]  AS errorcode
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

However, this is a very big table with hundreds of billions of events coming in per day.  The example I posted has been abstracted a bit, in actuality there are ~30 columns that I'm extracting.  So for each record in the table I'm effectively calling the SPLIT() function 30 different times.  This can lead to queries failing due to a lack of resources, etc.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I've been playing around with the idea of using procedural language to see if it's possible to split the record once, and then reference the different values..  for example, something like this:

```
DECLARE parsed DEFAULT (SELECT SPLIT("firstname lastname timestamp eventtype errorcode", " "));

SELECT 
parsed[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS first, 
parsed[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS last,
parsed[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS timestamp,
parsed[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS eventtype,
parsed[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS errorcode
```

This would prevent me from splitting the string 30 different times per record, but then I would need to have some way to perform this for each row.  It seems like there might be a way to do this with [User Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions), but I don't have much experience with them.

Any ideas?  Or is the SPLIT and SAFE_OFFSET approach really the most efficient way to approach this problem?

Comment: Just because you wrote split thirty times doesn't mean the engine evaluates it thirty times. SQL is not an imperative language (like, for example, C) it's declarative. That is, you declare an expression and then the engine chooses how to solve it. In this case it would see the repeated expression and only evaluate it once.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is the SPLIT and SAFE_OFFSET approach really the most efficient way to approach this problem?

Yes. I think so!

```
SELECT cols[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]  AS first,
       cols[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]  AS last,
       cols[SAFE_OFFSET(2)]  AS timestamp,
       cols[SAFE_OFFSET(3)]  AS eventtype,
       cols[SAFE_OFFSET(4)]  AS errorcode
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(unparsed_field, " ") AS cols)])
```